# two different kinds of citations in the same document

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing

I am using LyX with the default "article" document class. All the citations look as bracketed numbers [1], [2], etc. I want to have two different citation formats in the same document, according to the context, for example:

- "It is impossible to solve the problem exactly (Author1, Year1), however, recently an approximate solution has been suggested by Author2 (Year2)".

How can I do this?

Comment: This can be achieved with the `natbib` package, and its `authoryear` option. You also need a `natbib`-compatible bibliography style, like `plainnat`. Then, the commands `\citep{...}` and `\citet{...}` do exactly what you want. No idea, though, how this is accomplished with LyX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `LyX`, go to

> Document Settings > Bibliography > Natbib

Then when you go to

> Insert > Citation

you can change how the citation appears by changing the `Citation style` box. It will give you a preview of how it will look in the PDF.

Comment: I did this, and now all my citations look e.g. like this: "(author?) [15]" (i.e. a boldface string "author? was added... not the name of the author). This happens no matter what format I choose in Insert->Citation...

Comment: Can you post a [.lyx minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample)?

Comment: Note: The bibliography itself looks fine - all authors and years appear correctly. Only the citation doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I found a solution - right-click on the bibliography, and change the "style" from "plain" to "plainnat" :)

Comment: Glad it works now. For future LyX + BibTeX problems, note that LyX 2.1 should report Natbib errors. You can still see the BibTeX log in LyX by going to Document LaTeX Log and changing it to BibTeX.

Answer (score 1):

See below example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

It is impossible to solve the problem exactly \citep{au1}, however,
recently an approximate solution has been suggested by \citet{au2}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem[Author1(2009)]{au1}
Author1, {\it PLE} 3(6):19--64, 2009.

\bibitem[Author2(2010)]{au2}
Author2, {\it PLE}, 4(7):119--164, 2010.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As the OP uses LyX, this is at best a partial solution, as it doesn't say anything about where the different required elements is found in the LyX GUI. (Also, an unrelated note, don't use `\it`, `\bf` etc, but the new `\itshape`, `\bfseries` etc., see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516))